# Why is $\left(\sum \limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac1{n^3}\right)^3 \gt \sum \limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac1{n^4} $?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

> $$\displaystyle \left(\sum \limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac1{n^3}\right)^3 \gt \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac1{n^4} $$

Why is this true ?

The LHS can be written either as it is or like this: $\displaystyle \sum \limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac1{n^9}$ which is clearly smaller.

Comment: $(a+b)^3 = a^3 + b^3 + 3ab(a+b) \neq a^3 + b^3$ in general. We have $$1 < \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^4} < \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^3} < \left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^3}\right)^3.$$

Comment: The right hand side is $\zeta(4)$ which has a closed form in terms of $\pi$. You could take the cube root of this and attempt a proof from there.

Comment: @DanielFischer AHA! This should be an answer.

Comment: @pbs what does zeta mean here and what does it has to do with pi ?

Comment: The Riemann zeta functions is defined $\zeta(s)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty 1/n^s$ for $s>1$. When $s$ is an even positive integer greater than 1 the Riemann zeta function has closed form in terms of the Bernoulli numbers and $\pi$.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In general a power of a sum is different from the sum of powers, $(a+b)^3 = a^3 + b^3 + 3ab(a+b)$ coincides with $a^3 + b^3$ only if either (at least) one of $a,b$ is zero or $a+b = 0$. For sums with more terms or series, conditions for equality aren't so straightforward. Here we have

$$1 < \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^4} < \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^3} < \left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^3}\right)^3,$$

the first inequality because the first term in the series is $1$ and all further terms positive, the second because for $n > 1$ we have $\dfrac{1}{n^4} < \dfrac{1}{n^3}$, and the last because $x < x^3$ for all $x > 1$.

Answer (score 3):

As "pbs" stated we have $$\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{-3}\right)^3=\zeta(3)^3=1.7369...$$ and
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{-4}=\zeta(4)=1.08232...$$
and thus the left side is greater than the right side.

Answer (score 0):

I think you thought of it like this:
$$\left(\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{k^3}\right)^3=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\left(\frac1{k^3}\right)^3$$Which isn't true. In fact, we have $$\sum_{k=1}^n(a_k)^c<\left(\sum_{k=1}^na_k\right)^c\tag{1}$$Where $a_k>0$. This is because we could write the RHS as the LHS plus more terms.

To solve the problem, we first define $$\zeta(s)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{k^s}$$This is known as the zeta function. Your problem is thus proving that $\zeta(3)^3>\zeta(4)$. We know that $\zeta(3)>\zeta(4)$ (the terms after $k=1$ are bigger for $\zeta(3)$ than $\zeta(4)$) and since $\zeta(3)>1$ (the first term in the sum is $1$ and all the other terms are positive), $\zeta(3)^3>\zeta(4)^3$. Since $\zeta(4)$ is also greater than $1$, $\zeta(4)^3>\zeta(4)$. Thus $\zeta(3)^3>\zeta(4)$ and your problem is solved

I know this is overkill, but this is just for the sake of adding another answer and showing what you might have gotten confused.